# Serilog event not saved

Tags: serilog, seq, getseq

I'm trying to log to file / seq an event that's an API response from a web service. I know it's not best practice, but under some circumstances, I need to do so.
The JSON saved on disk is around 400Kb.to be honest, I could exclude 2 part of it (that are images returned as base64), I think I should use a destructured logger, is it right?
I've tried increasing the Seq limit to 1mb but the content is not saved even to log file so I think that's not the problem...I use Microsoft Logging (ILogger interface) with `Serilog.AspnetCore`

Is there a way I can handle such a scenario?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, you could use a destructurer to only include the properties you want. You can even [use attributes](https://nblumhardt.com/2014/07/using-attributes-to-control-destructuring-in-serilog/). Did you try it? What was the result? Did you [enable self logging](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics#selflog) as described in their documentation?

Answer (score 1):

You can [log a serialized value](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Writing-Log-Events) by using the `@` format option on the property name. For example,

```
Log.Information("Created {@User} on {Created}", exampleUser, DateTime.Now);
```

As you've noted it tends to be a bad idea unless you are certain that the value being serialized will always be small and simple.